# Finding source code (implementation) for runtime window

Tags: .net, winforms, form-control

When we use web application, we can view the current page details by seeing the view source. In my case i need to identify the current form displayed while running windows application. Is there any way to find this. My source have many forms and some forms are generated dynamically.

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you looking for a reference of current window within your application? Or any window system-wide? What kind of reference are you looking for? Windows handle? Or some higher-level reference (like `Form` instance in .NET)?

Comment: I need to know the Form name in current application which is opened. Since i can't find the right place to change the source code, it will be easy for me if i know the form name which is being shown.

Comment: Ok, see my answer. Also please update your question to make it clear what you look for. Use *edit* link.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for currently active instance of `Form` in your .NET application, use `Form.ActiveForm` static property.

To get the form name, use `Form.ActiveForm.Text`. To get the form type, use `Form.ActiveForm.GetType()`.

To have suitable place to evaluate the above, you can put following code somewhere at the beginning of the application (`Main`):

```cs
new System.Threading.Timer(
    delegate
    {
        Type activeFormType =
            (Form.ActiveForm != null) ? Form.ActiveForm.GetType() : null;
        Type breakpointHere = activeFormType;
    },
    null, 0, 10000);
```

Then run your application, open the form you want to inspect. Switch to VS and put breakpoint on line `string breakpointHere ...`. Switch back to your application and wait for the timer to fire and the debugger to stops on the breakpoint. Then check value of `activeFormType`.

Comment: Actually i am having source code of a tool. This tool has many forms and some forms are generated dynamically. I need to customize the tool. When the application is running i am opening the form which needs to be customized. How to find the name of currently opened form. In web application, i can view the data source to find the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Hawkeye](http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/)**

Hawkeye is a free utility.
It's like a dynamic property grid than can hook to any windowsform application. Once hooked to an application it will show properties, fields, type, methods...

When you hook it to a form, you'll see the form name (the object type)